# jQuery - enclose image in a div with a dynamically set width

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

**EDIT 1/27/12 11:32am - I believe I have fixed all issues associated with this script. I need to apply a CSS class to each image I want to resize depending on if I want to float it left, right or have it centered, but I can live with that. See my latest explanation and demo at http://evanwebdesign.com/responsive-web-design/example5.html**

**Edit 1/27/12 10:50am - There is still a problem with this script. See my comments below. Working on a fix.**

**EDIT 1/27/12 9:00am: I now have this problem nearly complete. See my example at http://www.evanwebdesign.com/responsive-web-design/example3.html and compare with my original examples**

I currently have an example of a responsive image that adjusts depending on the width of the browser window posted at http://evanwebdesign.com/responsive-web-design/example.html.

**EDIT 1/16/12: I have made a more elaborate example that (hopefully) makes my question easier to understand at http://evanwebdesign.com/responsive-web-design/example2.html**

But suppose I have multiple images within my #content div? And suppose they're all different widths? I don't want to manually calculate width values and create enclosing divs with custom classes for all of my images!

Instead I want to write a jQuery script that will do the following:

- Go through all images within the #content div
- Get the width of each image (I realize that I need to use $(window).load() for this otherwise I will wind up with an image value of 0)
- Take the image's width in pixels and divide it by 900. (900 is the arbitrary max-width pixel value of the #content div after the padding has been applied.)
- Take this new number created from the previous step apply it as a percentage to the width of a new containing div around the image.

**The goal is to dynamically create the .home_photo div for each image within the #content div.** I don't care if the CSS is written inline, as the markup will never appear in the HTML.

Please let me know if this question is clear, or if there is anything else I can do to better explain myself. I know there are a lot of steps involved with this question.

Thanks in advance to everyone for your help!

Comment: I'm no jQuery master so I got as far as getting the width of the image and posting it as an alert().

`$(window).load(
   function() {
    alert($(.home_photo).width());
   }
  );`

Comment: For what it's worth... I don't entirely understand the code in this example, but I think this is similar to what I'm trying to achieve: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723170/jquery-dynamic-image-resize]

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to wrap each image in a div that will be sized based on the image's native size relative to the main #content div.

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function()   {
   var contentWidth = $('#content').width();
   $("#container img").each(function(){
        var ratio = $(this).width()/contentWidth;
        $(this).wrap("<div style='width:"+ratio+"'></div>");
});
```

You mentioned window.load - $(document).ready is a better version to use with jQuery because it executes immediately after the DOM is loaded, rather than waiting for all resources (including images for example) on the page to load.

Comment: In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead. --Jquery.ready page

Comment: @Joel.d you are the man! What you wrote was _close_ but I needed to make a few modifications to make it work. One of them was the necessary window.load as mentioned by David Richard. Another was adding a "%" to the inline CSS of the jQuery-generated div. Finally, I had to give each image a width of 100% via jQuery because when I hard it coded in the CSS it didn't work. See my new example at http://www.evanwebdesign.com/responsive-web-design/example3.html

Comment: I'm realizing that there is a problem with this new example. When the page loads at screens with a smaller dimension, the images start out at their original pixel size. I am working on a solution right now.

Comment: I believe I have fixed the problem that I mentioned above. See my edits to the original question above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with css only

```
<style>
   .home_photo img
   {
        width:900px;
   }
</style>
```

Let me know if I misunderstood smthing

**EDIT**

I think this will do the trick

```
$(function(){
   $(window).resize(function(){
       $("#container img").each(function(){
        if($("#content").width() < $(this).width())
        {
            $(this).width($("#content").width());
        }
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: That's not exactly it. In order for the image(s) to display at their native size when the site is viewed at a 1024 resolution or higher, the containing element for the image needs to have a unique width that is manually set. Adding your CSS rule to the example works in this particular scenario, but if I was to add a 2nd image with a different width I would need to make a new CSS class for it (like .home_photo) but with a different value for the width. Sorry if this is confusing, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it , can you add in your example what do want to with the images . And I will try  do it automatically with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I posted a more detailed example of what I'm trying to do at http://evanwebdesign.com/responsive-web-design/example2.html